# Where is the bug in this function?

Tags: mysql, function

When I run the script down to create the function `getUser_ID()` I get this error:

[image]

function

```
create function getUser_ID() 
return int
begin 
declare user int;
select User_ID+1 into user from BX_Users order by  User_ID DESC limit 1;
return user;
end;
```

Comment: What if this is run concurrently/out of sequence? You could get the same value twice, this is what IDENTITY columns are for.

Comment: i dont understand you but when i run this request **select User_ID+1  from BX_Users order by  User_ID DESC limit 1 **
i have User_ID = 1000029

Comment: @AlexK.: Identity fields are used in MSSQL, MYSQL uses [AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Comment: In regards to the question though; Whats your table structure like? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i just went to get the last ID+1 to show it on authentification

Answer (score 1):

They keyword, in the declaration,  specifying the data type a stored function *returns* is `RETURNS`.  Not `RETURN`.

```
create function getUser_ID() RETURNS int
...
```